# Better way to debug Python Code in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, debugging, jupyter-notebook

I was wondering is there is a good and comprehensive way to debug python code step by step in Jupyter Notebook so that I can have a better idea of all the variables involved, their dimensions and values. So is there a tool like that or should I need to move to an IDE like Spyder?

Comment: If you use Jupyter Notebook from within VSCode then it works as normal but you can set breakpoints, see variable values, examine data structures and set watch expressions. See [link](https://pbpython.com/vscode-notebooks.html), Really useful and simple to set up.

Comment: JupyterLab is the current generation of Jupyter interface and has a debugger mode that allows you to step through code. See this post [here](https://twitter.com/rasbt/status/1540413702410731520) and [related one here](https://twitter.com/rasbt/status/1540448306492473346). Documentation is [here](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/debugger.html). Look under 'Tutorial Notebook' section on that page for a link where you can try it out without installing anything on your own system.

Comment: @Wayne Sorry for such a late reply, came here after getting a notification, Jupyterlab was good enough for what I needed, please post it as an answer so i can accept and close the question. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JupyterLab is the current generation of Jupyter interface and has a debugger mode that allows you to step through code. See this post [here](https://twitter.com/rasbt/status/1540413702410731520) and a [related one here](https://twitter.com/rasbt/status/1540448306492473346).

Documentation is [here](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/debugger.html).
You can try it out without installing anything on your own system by [clicking here](http://mybinder.org/v2/gh/binder-examples/requirements/HEAD) to launch a temporary Jupyter session running on a remote computer via the MyBinder service, and then open a new notebook file from the launcher. You can step the sections 'Debug code in notebook' and 'Explore the code state' [there in the documentation](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/debugger.html#debug-code-in-notebook).